# Defining variables in a for loop

Tags: python, variables, for-loop

I'm trying to define k variables looking like x1, x2, ...xn, where each is a list (each list has 5 elements). meaning:

something like this:

```
     for i in [1..100]:
              "x" + str(i) = [ i + 2, i + 3, i + 3, i + 2, i + 4] 
              print ""x" + str(i)", 'x' + str(i) 

    ideal  output:
              x1 = [3,4,4,3,5]
              x2 = ...
              x3
              x4 
               .
               .
               .
              x100 =
```

I am getting 'invalid syntax' messages. I'm open to anything that can get me over this fairly simple hurdle.

Comment: You definitely don't want to create a hundred variables, each called `x1, x2, x3...` Wouldn't you rather create a list that contains a hundred lists? That way you could access them as `x[0], x[1], x[2]...`

Comment: That sounds like a better plan. So I'd have one giant list? But, eventually I will be doing arithmetic on the lists. Can I do something like x[0] - x[1]?

Comment: @NilesBernoulli I think we'll be better able to help you if you give an idea of what problem you're trying to solve. The code you have right now looks like you're trying to create 100 different lists, which seems a bit silly.

Comment: By arithmetic, you mean you want to subtract all five of the items in one list from all five of the items in another? That's sort of a different question than this one: perhaps you should ask it separately (after all, you couldn't do `x1 - x2` in your approach). Or do you mean you want to do `x[0][0] - x[1][0]` or something like that?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, guys. I ideally want to be calculating distances like this. This is doing the distance function between two points in 5 dimensional space (5-tuple)

Take x1, x2. [ (x[1])[1]- (x[2])[1] ] ^ 2 + ..

Basically I have a list of 100 of these 5-tuples. and want to find the distance function between any two.

Comment: Python does not define tuple subtraction or exponentiation the way you want. If you're doing a lot of math, you may want to look into [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), which provides a variety of useful mathematical operations and an n-dimensional array type.

Comment: You should take a look at numpy. This should probably all he stored in a numpy matrix, and numpy has functions for distances and distance matrices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a list of lists. With a list comprehension, that'd be

```
lists = [[i+2, i+3, i+3, i+2, i+4] for i in range(1, 101)]
```

That's equivalent to the following `for` loop:

```
lists = []
for i in range(1, 101):
    lists.append([i+2, i+3, i+3, i+2, i+4])
```

Instead of writing `x1`, you'd write `lists[0]`. If you wanted to do math on the elements,

```
lists[3][2] - lists[6][3]
```

would be what you'd write instead of

```
x4[2] - x7[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `class` or with `globals` or `locals` dict for example:

```
class foo: pass

setattr(foo, 'variable', 'value')

print foo.variable
```

another example with `__dict__`:

```
 class bar:
    def add_var(self, variable, value):
        self.__dict__[variable] = value
bar = bar()
bar.add_var("variable", "value")
print bar.variable
```

an example with `globals`:

```
globals()['variable'] = "value"
print variable
```

the same with `locals`:

```
locals()['var'] = "value"
print var
```